# What does snuggling the pig do?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

In the farm, there is a pig which I have the option of snuggling.  Every time I do so, it just knocks me down and runs off into the woods.  Is this all that ever happens?  I just want to be friends.

Comment: It makes you _creepy and weird_. That's what it does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a running joke among the community that snuggling the pig before every mission increases your luck, but in reality snuggling the pig doesn't do anything except make the pig like you (which has no in-game effect). It's just something extra the developers added into the game for a little fun.

The reason the pig keeps running from you though is because **it hates you.** You really should snuggle it more often so it doesn't think you're a heartless pig hating robot.

Comment: But he's already made it very clear that [he loves pigs.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=8359749#8359749)

Comment: @Fluttershy I just want him to love me back :(

Comment: Heathen, do not spread lies of the hunter idol that is the pig. All true believers know that the porky one blesses hunters with many rubies, gems and plates.

Answer (score 0):

It can be considered to be practice for cooking meat. You have to wait through the tune and press A at just the right moment(when the exclamation point is above Poogie's head or right when the meat changes color) for success. Too late results in a mad pig or burnt meat.

Answer (score -1):

To make the Pig loves you, you have to press "A" in the right time, when the "!" appears at the pig's head. Is just for fun. The pig will follow you after this.